# Delete Row causes issue with Controller Seeing all elements of Table

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Currently I am working on a project in C# MVC5 that will have a list of musicians. This list of musicians in my view has the name of the input in my view as musician[i]. When i go to delete a row in the middle of my table it will remove an integer that causes discontinuity in the array. So when my i submit my table to my controller that has musicians 1 through 5 but musician 4 has been deleted it will also skip 5.

In short I am trying to figure out how to delete a row then change the index numbers of all objects to be flush... so if i have musicians[0], musicians[1], musicians[2] and i delete index 1 then it will shift musician of index to change to index 1 since there is nothing there.

I have attached my Javascript that i am using. Not really anything else than just html at this point and Javascript in my opinion but i could be missing something too?

Thanks in advance for any advice and help!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("click",
            ".classAddMusician",
            function () {
                var mrowCount = $('#musicianTableBody').children().length;
                var musicianObject = '<tr><td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="track.Musicians[' + mrowCount + '].FirstName" id="track.Musicians[' + mrowCount + '].FirstName" placeholder ="First Name" value=""></td>' +
                    '<td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="track.Musicians[' + mrowCount + '].LastName" id="track.Musicians[' + mrowCount + '].LastName" placeholder="Last Name" value=""></td>'+
                    '<td><button type="button" id="btnAddInstrument' + mrowCount + '" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAddMusician">Add More</button>' +
                    '<button type="button" id="btnDelete' + mrowCount + '" class="delete btn btn btn-danger btn-xs">Remove</button></td></tr>';
                $('#musicianTableBody').append(musicianObject); // Adding these controls to Main table class
            });
        $(document).on("click",
            ".delete",
            function () {
                $(this).closest("tr")
                    .remove(); // closest used to remove the respective 'tr' in which I have my controls
            });
    });
</script>
```

Controller (POST)

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(Track track)
    {
        var instruments = track.Instruments.ToList();
        track.Instruments.Clear();

        var musicianList = track.Musicians.ToList();
        track.Musicians.Clear();

        var composerList = track.Composers.ToList();
        track.Composers.Clear();

        if (!HelperMethods.HelperMethods.IsNullOrEmpty(musicianList))
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < musicianList.Count(); i++)
            {
                var tempFirstName = musicianList[i].FirstName;
                var tempLastName = musicianList[i].LastName;

                if(db.Musicians.Any(x => x.FirstName.Equals(tempFirstName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && x.LastName.Equals(tempLastName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
                {
                    musicianList[i] = db.Musicians.First(f => f.FirstName.Equals(tempFirstName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && f.LastName.Equals(tempLastName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
                }
                else
                {
                    musicianList.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }

            foreach(var x in musicianList)
            {
                track.Musicians.Add(x);
            }
        }

        if (!HelperMethods.HelperMethods.IsNullOrEmpty(instruments))
        {
            for(int i = 0; i< instruments.Count(); i++)
            {
                var tempInstrumentName = instruments[i].Name;
                if(db.Instruments.Any(x => x.Name.Equals(tempInstrumentName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
                {
                    instruments[i] = db.Instruments.First(f => f.Name.Equals(tempInstrumentName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
                }
                else
                {
                    instruments.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }

            foreach(var x in instruments)
            {
                Instrument inst = new Instrument();
                inst = x;
                track.Instruments.Add(inst);
            }
        }

        if (!HelperMethods.HelperMethods.IsNullOrEmpty(composerList))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < musicianList.Count(); i++)
            {
                var tempFirstName = composerList[i].FirstName;
                var tempLastName = composerList[i].LastName;

                if (db.Musicians.Any(x => x.FirstName.Equals(tempFirstName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && x.LastName.Equals(tempLastName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
                {
                    composerList[i] = db.Composers.First(f => f.FirstName.Equals(tempFirstName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && f.LastName.Equals(tempLastName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
                }
                else
                {
                    composerList.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }

            foreach (var x in musicianList)
            {
                track.Musicians.Add(x);
            }
        }


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(track).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(track);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be appending musicians one row at a time.
Incrementing the `mrowCount` variable as the index for each one.

You are then posting back the `input`s with their names; `track.Musicians[0].FirstName`, `track.Musicians[1].FirstName`, `track.Musicians[2].FirstName` etc.

You haven't supplied your controller's code, but I'll assume you are iterating over all of the `track.Musician[?]` items with an index.

If you delete one of these rows on the client, then the inputs you receive at the server will be missing one of these, i.e. `track.Musicians[0]`, `track.Musicians[2]`.

If you are iterating through these items you do not know how many were added or deleted. You may have had 100 musicians added, then 95 of them deleted; but which five were kept and what was the index used on each of them?

There are many ways to handle this, but here are a few of suggestions:

- After removing the `table row`, rename all of the `track.Musicians` in
  the remaining table rows starting from 0 to the last one (length -
  1).
- Capture the `onSubmit()` and iterate through all of the remaining
  controls who's name starts with 'track.Musicians[' and re-name them
  all starting from 0.
- Use an extra `hidden control` that stores the state of the musician
  (existing, added, or deleted). Then on a delete, only make the `table row` `hidden` - don't remove it. This way, all rows will be submitted
  back to the server and you can decide what needs to be done with each
  musician.
- Use an `array` to store the current musicians and push to it on an add,
  remove (`track.Musicians.splice(index, 1);`) on a delete. Bind the
  `table row` controls to the values in the `array` using a framework such
  as `knockout.js`, or redraw the `table` yourself if it is small. This way
  the `table` will update automatically when you add or remove musicians
  from the `array`.

When you submit your `form`, you will now have correctly indexed controls according to how many exist.

Of these I would recommend the third option out of personal choice. The `HTML` code would be smaller and cleaner.

Saying all this though, if you are editing an existing list of musicians, you would have to delete all existing musicians (for the applicable track) in the database and add all those submitted because you cannot match the indexes to those that have been saved.

You could add a `hidden input` that holds that particular `row`'s musician's id, then compare them on the server for either updating (for existing), adding (if new), and deleting if marked as such.

Comment: i saw that you requested the controller so i supplied a controller though i realized also that its not modifying the entity anyways which is on my list to fix! but anyways i will read over what you have given me to review! thanks!

Comment: Also noticed, your mrowCount is always the current number of musicians. If you add one, delete the first row, then add one, delete the first row etc. they will all have the same value...

Comment: Ah! yea i see what you mean... I get what you mean with hidden and it seems like a solid idea especially since that would solve the add/delete dilemma where some entries could end up with the same index number. Though i wouldn't know how to sift through that data once its passed back to the controller since i wouldn't be able to identify which data was hidden and which was not. Or rather I don't THINK that its possible

Comment: As well as hiding the row, you could update a hidden control on the row stating 'deleted' or some such thing, then you can delete it on the server (if it already exists).

Comment: Did this fix it for you @Mitaku? If so, could you mark it as the Answer please :)